# Imposing conditional entity relations

Tags: relational-database, application-design, entity, business-rules, relationships

While working on an application, I am facing an issue. And I am not sure how to solve this.

For explanation I have managed to come up with a simple example below:

Consider a Grocery Store application.

- It has a finite number(which means the items wont change often) of
  items.
- Each item is different than other and has its own properties. In this Example they're:

  - Orange
  - Book
  - Chocolate
- User would  add one or more instances above items in to a BASKET.

[image]

From conventional wisdom I decided to represent this structure in Relational DB as following tables:

- Created individual tables for ORANGE, BOOK, CHOCOLATE, and BASKET.
- And created a Mapping tables between above with BASKET.

This works out so far good. Here is the issue.

Once user saves the basket, at the process of checkout the store would impose some rules/discounts which are set for individual scenario, For example:

- If user's basket has 2 oranges, he can not checkout ROUND shaped chocolates.
- If user checkout basket between 10 AM and 12PM he is not allowed checkout books from author: Dan Brown.
- And some other rules, you can see where I am going with these.

User will not be aware of these above rules at the time of adding Items to basket. But these rules are imposed at the time of checkout.

My problem is HOW and WHERE should I store these rules?
I can not hard code them in application. They have to be stored somewhere as guidelines to cashier at the time of checkout.

I am not sure if I could articulate my issue properly but I have simplified this as much as I could.

If any one have any solutions please let me know.

Comment: Most likely, what you are looking for is a [Business Rules Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider having a `Rule` table.  For each row in a `Rule` table, you have a row in `RuleCondition`, a row in `RuleAction`, and n rows in `RuleParameters`.

`RuleCondition` describes the conditions for which the `RuleAction` is triggered.  For example, if time is between 10am and 12pm, or checkout basket contains 2 oranges.  `RuleCondition` also contains the name of the class which implements this rule condition.

`RuleAction` describes the action to be performed when `RuleCondition` is true.  This could be anything from invalidating the checkout to simply removing items from the checkout.  `RuleAction` also contains the name of the class which implements this rule action.

`RuleParameters`, having a foreign key to the Rule, is a many-to-one table containing all named parameters pertaining to this *specific* rule.  For example, to avoid having a `RuleCondition` for every possible time period, for rule conditions requiring a start and end time, in `RuleParameters`, you could create two parameters with names `startTime` and `endTime`.  The implementation of `RuleCondition` would be given the list of all parameters and the actual implementation of `RuleCondition` would use the parameters it needs.  Apply the same possibility to `RuleAction` as well.

You would need to create a `RuleEngine` class which loads all these rules and applies each rule action whose `RuleCondition` is satisfied during checkout.

From there sky's the limit.  I would expect there to be many Rules and `RuleParameters`, but not so many `RuleConditions` or `RuleActions` as they would be parameterized.  If you load these rules at every checkout or every 5 minutes or so, you can apply changes on the fly.  This could easily be given an interface as well, allowing the client to perform the changes as necessary.

Also, if I may make a small piece of advice, you should probably not have a table for each possible item.  While it's true they have their own data pertaining to it, you could just as easily have a `Product` table with `ProductInfo` key/value pairs with all information required for that product.  Or even a hybrid solution with `Produce` table with foreign key to `Product` table containing everything specific to produce products, allowing `ProductInfo` to be freed up somewhat.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer Neil. Could you please give one small example for your advise on Having one `PRODUCT` table for all different types of products?

Comment: @KishorPrakash Product table would contain all information pertaining to *all* products.  No reason why Orange should be treated differently than Shampoo in your program.  However your product table should also give you all the information you require to load everything about that product, so presumably you'd have a category column with "produce" in it.  You know that if you see "produce" category, you'll find more information about that product in the Produce table whose foreign key is the id of the Product table.

Comment: I am really sorry I could not fully understand with my thick skull :( I really like the idea of maintaining all the `items` in one table. which allows me to maintain an array of them in Java code as well. Could you please give an example or schema diagram for the scenario mentioned in the picture.

Comment: @KishorPrakash I cannot access the image from work.  My apologies.  Could you be more specific?  My point was that it isn't feasible to have a table for each product type, or you'll have literally hundreds of product tables with similar fields.  You cannot fit it all in one table either, so find a compromise without repeating data.  You should have a master product table for all products with information allowing you to gather additional information from other tables.